# Count from several columns Oracle Sql

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I have a table that contain the following:

```
Fruit_id     Fruit1            Fruit2
-------------------------------------
1            Apple             Orange
2            Orange            Orange
3            Orange            Orange
4            Banana            Banana
5            Apple             Orange
```

I would like to count the total number for each fruit so that the output is something like

```
Fruit            Frequency
---------------------------
Apple            2
Banana           2
Orange           6
```

I have tried

```
select distinct Fruit1, count(Fruit1 Fruit2) from Fruits group by Fruit1 order by count(Fruit1 Fruit2);
```

I also tried:

```
select distinct Fruit1, count(Fruit1 || Fruit2) from Fruits group by Fruit1 order by count(Fruit1 Fruit2);
```

I'm new to oracle sql so please understand my ignorance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the count for each distinct fruit value in the Fruit1 and Fruit2 columns, and then add those together with a SUM aggregate.

The "trick" is to use an inline view that concatenates the two results together with a UNION ALL set operator.

```
SELECT f.fruit, SUM(f.cnt) AS cnt
  FROM ( SELECT d.Fruit1 AS fruit, COUNT(1) AS cnt FROM Fruits d GROUP BY d.Fruit1 
          UNION ALL
         SELECT e.Fruit2 AS fruit, COUNT(1) AS cnt FROM Fruits e GROUP BY e.Fruit2
       ) f
 GROUP BY f.fruit
 ORDER BY f.fruit
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following:

```
select fruits, count(*) as freq
  from (select fruit1 as fruits
          from tbl
        union all
        select fruit2 as fruits
          from tbl)
 group by fruits
```

Comment: @user3619807 There is nothing wrong with the query, see it working at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/32c5c/1/0 . You may have mistyped something. The answer you accepted is actually the same as mine, just posted later.